# Is it possible to call a user-defined (custom) R function from within C#?

Tags: r, c#-4.0

Is it possible to call a user-defined (custom) R function from within C#?

For example a simple matrix multiplication function written in R:

```
matrix_mult = function(a, b) {
c = a %*% b;
return c;
}
```

How can I call this R function matrix_mult(a,b) from c#?

Comment: [Here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-R-API) is a link to the *R* manual section on *C* intefacing with *R*. Using P/Invoke it should be reasonably easy to apply corresponding calls from C# instead.

Comment: Can you give us more information about the context and reasons on why you want to call R form c#?

Comment: @agstudy in order to use a matrix function written in R with the Function Router construct in .net http://finaquant.com/function-router/2802

Answer (score 8):

After some research I've found an answer myself.

1) Open an existing or new project in MS Visual Studio.

2) Install R.NET (NuGet)
http://rdotnet.codeplex.com

Installation is easy: 
Menu: Visual Studio (2012) > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console
type "Install-Package R.NET"

3) Initialize a function in R and call it from C#
See http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation for data types in R

```
using RDotNet;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Set the folder in which R.dll locates.
    var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");

    // check the version and path on your computer
    var rBinPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin\x64";

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + System.IO.Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);

    using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
    {
        // Initializes settings.
        engine.Initialize();

        // create an R function
        // R style
        // See: http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

        Function matrix_mult = engine.Evaluate(@"matrix_mult <- function(a,b){ 
        c = a %*% b;
        return(c);
        }").AsFunction();

        NumericMatrix d = engine.Evaluate(@"d <- matrix_mult(a,b)").AsNumericMatrix();

        Console.WriteLine("Matrix d:");
        engine.Evaluate("print(d)");

        // convert NumericMatrix of R to double[,] of .net
        double[,] darr = new double[d.RowCount, d.ColumnCount];
        d.CopyTo(darr, d.RowCount, d.ColumnCount);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How can the matrices a and b be passed to the R function?

Comment: If someone wants to define some input in c# and then pass it to R, how one can do that? I wanted to pass a vector which is stored in some variable, same variable I was passing to the R input vector in the double quotes but  variable not found error appeared.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: In order to see how array parameters are passed from C# to R you may visit my article "Table data as input to estimation functions in R" at http://finaquant.com/table-data-as-input-to-estimation-functions-in-r/3082 see C# code examples under subtitle "Integration of R with table functions in C#"

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: Wrong tool chain. R on Windows is built with the MinGW gcc port.  Linking is somewhere between impossible to very fragile.

You can only do this with weak coupling using two machines, having [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) on one and a .Net / C# connection to it.  There are a few solution out there as eg [RserveCLI](http://rservecli.codeplex.com/).