# How to call a user defined function (in a .rdata file) from c# R.net?

Tags: c#, .net, r, s-plus, r.net

I have, in one hand, a plateform I developped in R, composed of many user-defined functions used to produce a report, using as inputs matrices and arguments.

In an other I manage my data flow through a `c#` Platform.

What I want to do is calling my `R` Platform from `c#` : calling a function defined in an `Rdata` file into my `c#` code (which handle all my data matrices).

I am familiar with `RdotNet` and use it to call user defined functions, but these are functions defined in my `c#` code itself, while I need to call functions in a `Rdata` file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [Is it possible to call a user-defined (custom) R function from within C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789417/is-it-possible-to-call-a-user-defined-custom-r-function-from-within-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R functions called from R.NET are not restricted to ones created from strings in .NET. If you define and save the function definition in R:

```
f <- function() {"Hello World"}
save(f, file='f.RData')
```

Then in C# you simply do something like

```
static void stackoverflow_27924923_2752565 (REngine engine)
{
    engine.Evaluate ("load('~/f.RData')");
    var s = engine.Evaluate ("f()").AsCharacter()[0];
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```