# Is it possible to Run R Code from Unity C# in Mono or .NET on OSX?

Tags: c#, r, macos, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Is there a way to run a R script using Unity's C# in Mono?

If there is no way to run an R script using Mono, I am willing to use .NET

**Update**

So the following code will call the R script but will not output a file if called from unity monodevelop. It would be ok to return a string to mono but changing the true and false on startInfo.UseShellExecute and startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput throws an error. Here is the C# code that will call the R code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "Rscript";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.dataPath + "/myUnity/Scripts/";
startInfo.Arguments = "Rexp1.R";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I know for sure that the R script will output a file or I can grab stdout and hold onto it. I will be happy with outputting to a file or having unity allow for a string to be returned that is the output of the R script.

Update 2* -
Here is the R script.

```
sink("output.txt")
nts <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 500)
ds <- dist(nts,method = "euclidean", diag = TRUE, upper=TRUE)
dm <- as.matrix(ds)  # distance matrix
print(dm)
sink()
```

Comment: I know that r.Net uses a framework that is too high for Unity

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this? For a plugin or you just want to make your game with R?

Comment: I would like to use some functions built into R. R is a very powerful scientific research language and it could be used to shorthand many operations. I suppose you could use it for a game but I am doing research.

Comment: Yes, but not directly like you can in C or C++. You can but this is not worth it as it may not work on mobile devices. Look [here](http://finaquant.com/calling-user-defined-functions-in-r-from-within-c/3060), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576456/is-there-a-way-to-call-r-functions-from-c-sharp-and-retrieve-the-result-in-c-sha) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14791768/3785314)

Comment: If it will work then that work be great. I never intend on supporting mobile devices.

Comment: I will look some more at the other options but I know R.Net is not useable because of target framework being higher than what Unity supports

Comment: Well I'll see if anyone has any ideas, two of the options so far use R.NET which is not compatible with Unity and the third option used R-(D)COM which is only for windows.

Comment: what R function are you trying to call? R isn't some magical language that can't be re-coded in C#.  You'd be surprised at how much libraries such as http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ and http://www.extremeoptimization.com/ can do.  (not affiliated with either one other than a guy who has used both to translate complicated R code in to C#)

Comment: I'm not trying to recode a language into another language. It is common to have code of one language wrapped inside another language. I attached an example R script. Hopefully, that helps

Comment: At times it is also common to have to rewrite a function in the language you need it in.

Comment: Perhaps [Rinside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) can help, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read from the output of the process like what you have done.

I don't have a MAC computer, but it should be the same. See comments in the code.

Your R script has error on my machine, so it output to stderr instead of stdout.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RunR : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        // For macOS, here should be
        //     I. "/bin/sh"
        //     II. "path_of_the_Rscript"
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe";
        // For macOS, here should be
        //     I. "-c path_of_the_Rscript Rexp1.R" if "/bin/sh" is used
        //     II. "Rexp1.R" if "path_of_the_Rscript" is used
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "Rexp1.R";
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.dataPath;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        //read the output
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Debug.Log(output);
        Debug.LogError(err);
    }
}
```

Ouput:

[image: Ouput]

Note the project view. There are a `Rexp1.R` and a `RunR.cs`. The first output is `Object`, because there is no output from stdout and thus output is null.

After I changed the content of Rexp1.R to the following,

```
print("12345")
print("ABCDE")
```

the output in console view becomes:

[image: normal output]

**UPDATE:**

After installing the igraph package and removing `sink("output.txt")` and the last `sink()`, the output is:

[image: possible correct output]

Comment: The R script threw an error because you needed to install the igraph library. The command to install the library can be added to the code or ran from the R command terminal : 'install.packages("igraph")'. I am still checking everything else but this looks like it should work. In any case, Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I was able to get this working. It took me a minute because I forget to add the '/' before the folder path in the workingdirectory assignment. process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.dataPath + "/Scripts". After I found that, everything was good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a side note for anyone who stumbles upon this answer trying to run R code through Unity. The method here could be used to run python, C, C++, or any number of other programming language scripts. This is incredibly helpful and is a cross platform (OSX or Windows) solution.